# How to tell connection timeout and socket timeout from exception trace stack?

Tags: java, android

I used apache http client lib in my program. I set both connection timeout and socket timeout for network calls. My understanding is that, if there is connection timeout, the client didn't reach the backend server; if there is socket timeout, the client reached the backend server but the server was not responding or very slow.

I log the following exception trace stack. How can I tell which timeout (connection or socket) caused the exception? Thanks!

```
java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out
at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connectStreamWithTimeoutSocketImpl(NativeMethod)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connectStreamWithTimeoutSocket(OSNetworkSystem.java:130)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:247)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:534)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1056)
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
```

Comment: Is there more to the stack trace? Because it will usually point to the exact line in your code where the exception was thrown. Also, from this stack trace, it appears that it was a connection timeout...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stack trace, you can tell that it timed out while attempting to [establish the connection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect%28java.net.SocketAddress%29), not while trying to read from the [Socket's InputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream%28%29).